# Why does JavaScript work when testing a webpage locally, but not once it is uploaded on the server?

Tags: javascript, html, css, server, local

so I'm building a voice recorder using JavaScript, and the voice recording works just fine when I run the .html with the script locally, however as soon as I upload it to the server, the .html page displays just fine, but the script no longer works - as in when the button is clicked, there is no prompt to get user's microphone permission or anything.

The webpage I hosted the recorder is [notfungi.com](http://notfungi.com).

Appreciate any help!

Comment: Hi, please check out [how to ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and add a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) to your post.

Comment: I would check the console in devtools. Probably your js files are not fetched properly .

Comment: are you using relative paths o absolute paths?...can you check inside the network tab in the dev tools if the js file is being loaded?...console shows any error?

Comment: **Always** check the error console. You will find a lot of info to start solving the issue itself.  The first step of debugging **any** javascript errors is to check the error console.

Comment: Thanks for the input guys, I will be on top of the console from now one! I'm a budding dev, thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that you are using `navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia` from a non-secure page. So you are getting an error about navigator.mediaDevices being undefined. Check in your developer tools console and you will see the error.

For more details on the security for `getUserMedia` follow this link: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MediaDevices/getUserMedia#security

Comment: Thank you! I will install an SSL certificate and all should be cake